# How to delete all duplicate records except one from a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, rdbms

Suppose there is table containing 10 records out of which 5 are exactly same (**this means there is no primary key or unique key in that table**), so the question is "*write an SQL query to delete all duplicate records leaving only one record out of those 5 duplicate records*", so finally there must be 6 records in that table which are distinct.
Actually I was asked this question today in an interview, and I couldn't answer it. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Is this mysql or postgres? Its currently taged with both.

Comment: anything would do. I just need the logic.

Comment: Just search, there are many ways like [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/removing-duplicates-from-a-table-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL:

Following is a sample table/data

```
CREATE TABLE ident (
    a INT
    ,b INT
    ,c INT
    );

INSERT INTO ident
SELECT generate_series(10, 14)
    ,generate_series(100, 104)
    ,generate_series(210, 214);

INSERT INTO ident
SELECT unnest(array [1,1,1,1,1])
    ,unnest(array [1,1,1,1,1])
    ,unnest(array [1,1,1,1,1]);
```

since the table doesn't have `primary/unique` we can use `ctid`.

**ctid**

> The physical location of the row version within its table. Note that
>   although the ctid can be used to locate the row version very quickly,
>   a row's ctid will change if it is updated or moved by VACUUM FULL.
>   Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier. The OID, or
>   even better a user-defined serial number, should be used to identify
>   logical rows.

```
select ctid,* from  ident;
```

will give you following rows

```
ctid   a  b   c   
------ -- --- --- 
(0,1)  10 100 210 
(0,2)  11 101 211 
(0,3)  12 102 212 
(0,4)  13 103 213 
(0,5)  14 104 214 
(0,6)  1  1   1   
(0,7)  1  1   1   
(0,8)  1  1   1   
(0,9)  1  1   1   
(0,10) 1  1   1
```

we should use windows function to find the `ctid` of identical rows

```
SELECT ctid
        FROM (
            SELECT ctid
                ,row_number() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY a
                    ,b
                    ,c ORDER BY ctid
                    ) rn
            FROM ident
            ) t
        WHERE rn > 1
```

and delete rows from the table

```
DELETE
FROM ident
WHERE ctid IN (
        SELECT ctid
        FROM (
            SELECT ctid
                ,row_number() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY a
                    ,b
                    ,c ORDER BY ctid
                    ) rn
            FROM ident
            ) t
        WHERE rn > 1
        );
```

[***sqlfiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/be212/4)

***OR***

you can simply use

```
delete from ident where  ctid not in (
select min(ctid) from ident group by a,b,c
)
```

Comment: And a similar method will work for Oracle by using ROWID instead of CTID

Comment: @DavidAldridge Thanks for the headsup, I havnt used _Oracle_

Answer (score 3):

Here I have used a window function, A column or two that is different from other distinct 5 rows to make the records unique from the duplicated 5 rows may enter in window function after `partition by` separated by commas. 
 **Note**: PostgreSQL syntax used.

```
 ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN id SERIAL;
 UPDATE table_name SET id = DEFAULT;
 ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE id IN 
(SELECT id  FROM (SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY column_name ORDER BY id) AS rnum
                     FROM table_name) t
              WHERE t.rnum > 1);
```

check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d175b)

Comment: question states there is no key; all rows are completely identical

Comment: @Bohemian Yes I corrected the description. If he says 5 records are identical and 5 are exactly the same. There must be a column to differentiate among them. So that column can be used.

Comment: no, there must *not* be another column to differentiate the rows. It is possible to create a table without a key.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes I agree its possible. I created a table similar to your SQL Fiddle (check my SQL fiddle) and executed my queries, by differentiating them by the column `a` as named in your table. (mine its `column_name1`). It gives the desired output. I assumed the column `column_name1` to be unique after  deletion of duplicates . If needed other columns also can be used so it will be composite after deletion.

Comment: I didn't read the question as implying each column be unique, but rather that `select distinct *` returns the same number of rows as `select *`.

Answer (score 3):

you achieve it in following steps.

1) store distinct record in temp table .

2) Truncate the original table .

3) Insert the data from temp to original.

`select * into #tmp from original_table where 1=2
insert into #tmp select distinct * from original_table .
truncate table original_table 
insert into original_table select * from #tmp`

Comment: This is certainly a guaranteed method for all RDBMS, but for particular versions there are more efficient in-place methods that rely on row_number or a pseudocolumn that is guaranteed to be unique ("ctid" for PostgreSQL, "rowid" for Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no clue and this is a genuine request for help...

Firstly, this question is:

1. A bit ridiculous. Whoever created the table without a key should be sacked
2. Pretty tough for an interview question

If you count multiple queries separated by semi-colons as one "query, here a mysql solution:

```
alter table mytable add column id int primary key auto_increment;
delete t1
from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t1.id < t2.id
  and t1.a = t2.a and t1.b = t2.b and t1.c = t2.c;
alter table mytable drop column id
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/910511/1).

Comment: Re (1), there are LOTS of keyless tables out there. Almost every system I've worked with has had many many tables with no natural keys at all.